# SES: 'Disable Active Rule Set' with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ses

In the SES, 'Rule Sets' console, with an active 'Rule Set', we can click the 'Disable Active Rule Set' button to disable the active rule set.

How do we do this with the aws cli?

In `$ aws ses set-active-receipt-rule-set help`, there is a `NOTE` which says:

```
To  disable  your email-receiving through Amazon SES completely, you
can call this API with RuleSetName set to null.
```

I have tried both:

```sh
aws ses set-active-receipt-rule-set --cli-input-yaml 'RuleSetName: null'

aws ses set-active-receipt-rule-set --rule-set-name=
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the command and don't specify that option at all.

```
$ aws ses set-active-receipt-rule-set
```

This will deactivate the active rule set so that none are active.